# Shell script to merge properties file (sed/awk/comm/diff) for rpm upgrade

Tags: shell-script, rpm, merge

We're developing a java product that's installed via rpm.
We have a set of config files that a user can edit. These config files are java properties files in the form:

```
com.acme.pkg1.setting=something customized 1
com.acme.pkg2.setting=something original 2
```

These files are marked in the SPEC file with %config(noreplace), so after an upgrade, we could have an .rpmnew file next to it:

```
com.acme.pkg1.setting=something original 1
com.acme.pkg2.setting=something original 2
com.acme.pkg3.setting=something original 3
```

Is there a way to merge these files in such a way that only new keys are added to the original file?

My idea was:

1. filter the keys
2. sort the keys
3. use comm(1), something like: comm -23 file.rpmnew.keys file.keys > new.keys
4. extract key=value from file.rpmnew matching new.keys
5. append result to original file

How can we achieve all this in from an rpm post-update script?

Preferably using only standard linux utilities (comm, diff, sed, awk, grep, ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Build raw original and raw target values without settings:

  ```
  sed "s/=.*//g" file_original.ini > file_original.raw
  sed "s/=.*//g" file_target.ini > file_target.raw
  ```
- I assume that target will have more options than the original. Build the difference:

  ```
  grep -vf original.raw target.raw > newvals.dat
  ```
- Add the new Values:

  ```
  cp -p file_original.ini file_original.ini.rpmsave
  grep -f newvals.dat file_target.ini >>file_original.ini
  ```

That`s the basic idea. It needs lots of error handling, clean tmp-file creation and tidying up.

Comment: Great idea to use grep -vf. To avoid any false matches, I had to escape "." in the keys before passing it to grep -f. A simple 'sed "s/\./\\\./g"' did the trick.